# Proving null quantification

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I was reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317791/can-you-ignore-unused-quantifiers) question and one of the answers talked about Null Quantification, particularly it said that if $\varphi$ is a wff that does not contain $x$ as a free variable then:

$\forall x \varphi \Leftrightarrow \varphi$

I know that this seems trivial, but is there a way to prove it? I tried to but was unable. My main concern when attempting a proof is that the order in which the quantifiers are placed is important. Any light shed would be much appreciated.

Comment: To prove it you need a logic.

Comment: Two ways: (i) use the proof system. What is your proof system ? Natural Deduction ? (ii) use *semantics*.

Comment: See similar post: [semantic proof of $\varphi \models \forall x \varphi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530740/semantic-proof-of-varphi-models-forall-x-varphi).

Comment: For the other "direction", see [Universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation).